# Visual Studio Code not updating to 1.84 on Mac OS Sonoma 14.0

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm currently on VSCode 1.83.1. Automatic updates are enabled. It downloads to 1.84 according to the release notes but upon restarting VSCode it's still at 1.83.1 and does seem to be updating. Auto update will keep doing the same thing over and over again without actually performing the proper update.

I've disabled extensions. Nothing changed. I cannot see anything in the cache folder to delete(assuming I found the right cache folder). I could not find any question answering the specific issue I have. I was hoping to delete the previous cache in order to allow for the update to work.

There is no folder with the path "/Users//Library/Application Support/Code/Local Storage" on my Mac OS.

Comment: I was able to install it be it is buggy, seems to have a memory leak https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/184542 - at this point I wish I did not update to Sonoma and VSCode 1.84.1

Comment: why do you mention the path in your last paragraph? is it related to a diagnostic message you're getting? if so, where are you getting it and when?

Comment: @starball there was no diagnostic message. According to another stackoverflow question, it said to clear cookies and cache in the path mentioned in the question. But that path is not on my MacOS

Comment: can you please edit your question to link to that question post in the place where you mention its answer?

Comment: @starball I don’t have access to that question at this time. If you know what the issue with vscode on macOS sonoma is, any help is appreciated.